# How to get the address of a Julia script file within itself?

Tags: julia

I have a `test.jl` Julia script file in a directory, e.g., `/home/directory1`. Assume that I want to save the output of this code as a `.txt` file in the same directory. My problem is that, obviously, the `.txt` file will be saved in the working directory of Julia, which by `pwd()` is somewhere else, e.g., `/home/julia/`.

I wonder how can I change the working directory in the `test.jl` script WITHOUT writting the directory address, `/home/directory1` , manually? I know that I can change the working directory by `cd("/home/directory1")`, but the problem is that I don't want to write the address manually. Is there any way to get the directory address of `test.jl` within itself by a command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get that information using macro `@__FILE__`

```
help?> @__FILE__
  @__FILE__ -> AbstractString

  Expand to a string with the path to the file containing the macrocall, or an empty string if evaluated by julia -e <expr>. Return nothing if the macro was missing parser source information. Alternatively see PROGRAM_FILE.
```

Example:

```
julia> open("c:\\temp\\some.jl","w") do f
       println(f, "println(\"Running at \$(@__FILE__)\")")
       end

julia> include("c:\\temp\\some.jl")
Running at c:\temp\some.jl

shell> julia "c:\temp\some.jl"
Running at c:\temp\some.jl
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Your solution resolved my issue.

Comment: Even better, use `@__DIR__` that resolves to the _directory_ of the current file...